# Rhomboid muscles

Tags: stretching

I have been told by the physio that my right rhomboid muscle is tight. As a result I am getting some pain in that area, especially when I breath deeply (Which is impacting my running).

What are some exercises to stretch and relax the rhomboid muscles?

Comment: Have you tried to google "stretching rhomboids"?

Comment: What stretching exercises did your physio give you for your rhomboids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EXRX is usually my go to site for queries like this. Here is the link for their [Rhomboid specific stretches](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/BackWt.html#anchor854426). However, as stated following your physios advice will be your best bet.

You may also want to look into foam roller massages for yor back to help stretch your muscles out.